# Convert AMPL Model to ORTools

Tags: python, or-tools, ampl

I am trying to convert my AMPL Model to ORTools. This is the model:

```
set NUTR;
set FOOD;

param cost {FOOD} > 0;
param f_min {FOOD} >= 0;
param f_max {j in FOOD} >= f_min[j];

param n_min {NUTR} >= 0;
param n_max {i in NUTR} >= n_min[i];

param amt {NUTR,FOOD} >= 0;

var Buy {j in FOOD} >= f_min[j], <= f_max[j];

minimize Total_Cost:  sum {j in FOOD} cost[j] * Buy[j];

subject to Diet {i in NUTR}:
   n_min[i] <= sum {j in FOOD} amt[i,j] * Buy[j] <= n_max[i];
```

This is my semi python code for ORTools. I don't know if Buy is correct and how to add the constraint:

```
Buy = {}
for f_ in FOOD:
    Buy[f_] = solver.IntVar(0, 1000, 'Buy[%s]' % (f_,))


##  Objective Function
Total_Cost = solver.Sum([cost[j_] * Buy[j_] for j_ in FOOD])



##  Constraints
for i in NUTR:
    for j in FOOD:
        print(amt[i,j] *Buy[j])
        #solver.Add( solver.Sum(amt[i,j] * Buy[j] <= n_max[i]  ))

solver.Minimize(Total_Cost)
```

Comment: Are `cost[]`, `nmax[]` and `amt[,]` just integer arrays defined somewhere else? Since * is overloaded for IntVar's, this expression `(amt[i,j] *Buy[j])`  is a LinearExpr that might not make sense to  print. It's not clear what you're trying to sum with `solver.Sum(amt[i,j] * Buy[j] <= n_max[i]  )` -- you've given a numerical comparison as argument to the method instead of a list of IntVar's

Answer (score 0):

wrong parenthesis

```
  solver.Add( solver.Sum(amt[i,j] * Buy[j]) <= n_max[i] )
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This is a python error. The issue should be closed in fact.